# Using a button with HTML and JS in Markdown

Tags: javascript, html, jupyter-notebook, markdown

I have this code in a markdown cell in Jupyter Notebook which I want to use to give the user a hint if they are struggling to solve a particular problem. The following code manages to create and display a clickable button, but when I click it, nothing happens. Any suggestions on what I can do so that when the button is pressed, the text inside my div tag will be revealed?

```
<button onclick="toggle_visibility('hidden-content')">Click to reveal hint</button>

<div id="hidden-content" style="display:none">
You can use len(my_list % 2 == 0 to check if the length of the list is even
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if(e.style.display == 'block')
            e.style.display = 'none';
        else
            e.style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Your code works fine (https://jsfiddle.net/Lhcpg0eu/). Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Seems to be a jupyter notebook specific issue, ive been able to get it working in any other form of markdown or html just not my .ipynb file. Ill try another method and report back here if I find anything.

Answer (score 0):

The code may work in jsFiddle, that doesn't mean it will work in the OP's framework or that the `script` tag will be parsed by the markdown to HTML transpiler, which is probably reHype. What is most likely happening is the `button` tag is allowed to be parse but `script` tags are not.

The only solution to this is to somehow load an external script that creates an event listener to handle the click of your button. I've never used your framework so I have no idea how to accomplish this. Also, you should get in the habit of using event listeners rather than invoking a function via the `onclick` property.

Here's an example:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.some-button');
button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  console.log(button.dataset.content);
  alert(button.dataset.content);
});
```

```html
<button class="some-button" type="button" data-content="hidden-content">Click Me</button>
```